# How do I add a loot table to an item in a loot table in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a minecart with a loot table within the block loot table I am making. I have already started in the process, and I know that I have up to that point formatted corectly, but I don't know the NBT tag formatting for adding the loot table... or if it is even possible in the first place... can someone please help? I am using the most recent 1.14 snapshot but it should be compatible with 1.13 format since that is what I've been using for everything else.

Here is what I have

> "functions": [
>               {
>                 "function": "set_data",
>                 "data": 0
>               },
>               {
>                 "function": "set_nbt",
>                 "tag": "{NBT}"
>               }

I just don't know what to replace NBT with to get what I ask?

I know the loot table I want to use is named "abandoned_mineshaft" and is found under the "chests" default loot tables.

I already tried "{LootTable:\"minecraft:chests/abandoned_mineshaft\"}" (take away the \'s and it is what you use for /summon) for the NBT tag as well as "{BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:\"minecraft:chests/abandoned_mineshaft\"}}" so I don't know where to go next...

An alternate solution that'd work for what I hope to accomplish is if the data pack could summon the minecart like infested blocks summon silverfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of update 18w46a this is impossible to do with a chest_minecart, however, to do it with a chest, another function is needed to be used.

> "function": "set_loot_table",
>   "name": "*path:to/loot_table*"